# Maximum number of points that lie on the same straight straight line in a 2D plane

Tags: math, hashmap, geometry

I am trying to solve a programming interview question that requires one to find the maximum number of points that lie on the same straight straight line in a 2D plane. I have looked up the solutions on the web. All of them discuss a O(N^2) solution using hashing such as the one at this link: [Here](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/04/leetcode-max-points-on-a-line-java/)

I understand the part where common gradient is used to check for co-linear points since that is a common mathematical technique. However, the solution points out that one must beware of vertical lines and overlapping points. I am not sure how these points can cause problems? Can't I just store the gradient of vertical lines as infinity (a large number)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Three *distinct* points are collinear if

```
x_1*(y_2-y_3)+x_2*(y_3-y_1)+x_3*(y_1-y_2) = 0
```

No need to check for slopes or anything else. You need need to eliminate duplicate points from the set before the search begins though.

So pick a pair of points, and find all other points that are collinear and store them in a list of lines. For the remainder points do the same and then compare which lines have the most points.

The first time around you have `n-2` tests. The second time around you have `n-4` tests because there is no point on revisiting the first two points. Next time `n-6` etc, for a total of `n/2` tests. At worst case this results in `(n/2)*(n/2-1)` operations which is `O(n^2)` complexity.

PS. Who ever decided the canonical answer is using slopes knows very little about planar geometry. People invented homogeneous coordinates for points and lines in a plane for the exact reason of having to represent vertical lines and other degenerate situations.

Comment: This is using the matrix determinant method right? Does it work for n >= 2 distinct points?

Comment: The test works only for 3 points. You can't take the determinant of a non-square matrix. Like I said. Pick two points at a time, and find all other points that are co-linear one at a time.

Comment: If I understood correctly, this method would take O(N^3) time since there are O(N^2) possible pairs and we can choose O(N) possible points for each pair? This is worse than the O(N^2) solution using slopes. I don't think that there is any way to optimise this solution since matrix determinant only works for 3 points.

Comment: Not exactly. If you test point _C_ using the pair of points _A_ and _B_ then there is no reason to use the pair _A_ and _C_ later, or _B_ and _C_.  This ends up being a `O(n^2)` operation. See answer edit.